# IO error in savetxt while using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to read a dataset and collect meta features from it.
I get the following error after executing the python file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runmeta.py", line 79, in <module>
    np.savetxt('datasets/'+str(i)+'/metafeatures',meta[i],delimiter=',')    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 940, in savetxt
    fh = open(fname, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/2/metafeatures'
```

Comment: Does `datasets/2/` exist?

Comment: Either you do not have permission to access the directory, or the directory does not exist. The confusion might also stem from given path being a *relative* path, which might not be correct from the caller's point of view (aka current working directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you're getting is simply telling you it didn't find the file. i would suggest looking into absolute and relative file paths.

advice in error handling:
the error is triggered on this line

```
fh = open(fname, 'w')
```

so as you debug your program, look at the line python shows you. maybe change the variable fname. that is where i would start.
currently

```
fname = 'datasets/2/metafeatures'
```